# Switching views in WPF, high level design question

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So I am currently working on a UI written in WPF. One thing I really like about WPF is the way it leads you to write more decoupled, isolated UI components.  One pain point for me in WPF is that it leads you to write more decoupled, isolated UI components that sometimes need to communicate with one another :).  This is probably due to my relative lack of UI experience, especially in WPF (I'm not a novice, but most of my work is far more low level than UI design).

Anyway, here is the situation:

At any one time, the central area of the UI displays one of three views implemented as `UserControl`s, let's call them Views A, B, and C.

The user will be switching between these views at various times, and there is more than one way to switch views (this works well for the customer, causes some pain in code design currently).

Right now each view switching mechanism does its own thing to transition to another view.  A certain singleton class takes care of storing data and communicating between the views.  I don't like this, it's messy, error prone, and the singleton class knows way too much about the details of the UI.  I want to eliminate it as much as is possible.

I ran into a bug today that had to do with the timing of switching between views.  To make it simple, one view needs to perform some cleanup when it is unloaded, but that cleanup erases some data that is needed for another view.  If the cleanup runs *after* the other view is loaded, problems ensure.  See what I mean?  Messy.

I am trying to take a step back and imagine a different way to get these views loaded with the data they need to do their job.  Some of you more experience UI / WPF people out there must have come across a similar issue.  I have a couple of ideas, but I am hoping someone will present a cleaner approach to me here.  I don't like depending upon order of operations (at a high level) for my code to work properly.  Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: You mention MVVM - are you working View-First or ViewModel-First for your MVVM approach?  (It makes some difference as to the best approach here, IMO)

Comment: @Reed: Viewmodel first, thanks Reed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend some kind of parent ViewModel that handles the CurrentView. I wrote an example [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/) a while back if you're interested.

Basically the parent view will have a `List<ViewModelBase> AvailablePages`, a `ViewModelBase CurrentPage`, and an `ICommand ChangePageCommand`

How you choose to display these is up to you. My preferred method is a `ContentControl` with it's `Content` bound to the `CurrentPage`, and using `DataTemplates` to determine which `View` should be displayed based on the `ViewModel` stored in `CurrentPage`

Comment: +1 This is basically my approach.  The only thing I'd add is this doesn't (necessarily) provide a clean way to handle a child view requesting a change to another child view, without additional information.  This can be handled fairly easily in many ways, including having a shared VM interface for children and subscribing on the parent VM, or using some form of messaging and/or a service to handle communication between VMs.

Comment: If that's the case, I usually use something like PRISM's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger` to broadcast a `ChangeViewMessage`, and have whatever control is handling the current view subscribe to those messages and handle them. I actually wrote something about communication between ViewModels too :) http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/

Comment: Yeah - both of these are effectively a messaging/service approach, which is a great option if you're going to be doing this in multiple places in the app.

Comment: I do use Prism's EventAggregator and one of my ideas was very similar.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer me here, I like this approach a lot.

Comment: how would you handle each page overlays ? In CM it was big pain because of many gotchas.

Answer (score 2):

[Rachel's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265156/switching-views-in-wpf-high-level-design-question/7272430#7272430) sums up my basic approach to this, quite well.  However, I would like to add a few things based on your comments which you may want to consider here.

Note that this is all assuming a ViewModel-first approach, as mentioned in comments.

> The user will be switching between these views at various times, and there is more than one way to switch views (this works well for the customer, causes some pain in code design currently).

This shouldn't cause pain in the design.  The key here is to have a single, consistent way to request a "current ViewModel" change, and the View will follow suit automatically.  The actual mechanism used in the View can be anything - changing the VM should be consistent.

Done correctly, there should be little pain in the design, and a lot of flexibility in terms of how the View actually operates.

> Right now each view switching mechanism does its own thing to transition to another view. A certain singleton class takes care of storing data and communicating between the views. I don't like this, it's messy, error prone, and the singleton class knows way too much about the details of the UI. I want to eliminate it as much as is possible.

This is where a coordinating ViewModel can really ease things.  It does not require a singleton, as it effectively "owns" the individual ViewModels of the views.  One option here, that's fairly simple, is to implement an interface on the ViewModels that includes an event - the ViewModel can raise the event (which I would name based more on what the intent is, not based on the "view change").  The coordinating VM would subscribe to each child VM, and based on the event, change it's "CurrentItem" property (for the active VM) based on the appropriate content to make the request.  There are no UI details at all required.

> I ran into a bug today that had to do with the timing of switching between views. To make it simple, one view needs to perform some cleanup when it is unloaded, but that cleanup erases some data that is needed for another view. If the cleanup runs after the other view is loaded, problems ensure. See what I mean? Messy.

This is screaming out for a refactoring.  A ViewModel should never clean up data it doesn't own.  If this is occurring, it means that a VM is cleaning up data that really should be managed separately.  Again, a coordinating VM could be one way to handle this, though it's very difficult without more information.

> I don't like depending upon order of operations (at a high level) for my code to work properly.

This is the right way to think here.  There should be no dependencies on order within your code if it can be avoided, as it will make life much simpler over time.

> I am trying to take a step back and imagine a different way to get these views loaded with the data they need to do their job.

The approach Rachel and I are espousing here is effectively the same approach I used in my [series on MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) to implement the master-detail View.  The nice thing here is that the "detail" portion of the View does not always have to be the same type of ViewModel or View - if you use a `ContentPresenter` bound to a property that's just an `Object` (or an interface that the VMs share), you can easily switch out the Views with completely different Views merely by changing the property value at runtime.

Comment: I have to chose someone to award the 15 extra points to and Rachel posted the general approach first, but I really appreciate you taking  the time to write all of this out.  This sounds like the right approach to me, I'll be implementing it shortly.  Thanks again and +1

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for this is to have one main view model that coordinates everything (not static / singleton) that you then use sub view models to transfer data around.  This keeps the decoupling you are looking for, provides testability, and allows you to control when the data for each object is changed.